# Check property values with special characters refactor

Tags: c#, refactoring

```
I have some class:

public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    ...
}

string specialCharacters = @"~!@#$%^&*_+|{}:""<>?[];'/=\№";
```

And I have method for checking :

```
    private bool CompareCharacters(string specialCharacters, AddressViewModel x)
    {
        if (x.Index.Any(specialCharacters.Contains) || 
            x.Area.Any(specialCharacters.Contains) || ...) 
           return false;
        else
           return true;
    }
```

How Can I refactoring this method? I don't like "if" statement implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, your desired behavior is to check whether your properties contains any of the characters in the specialCharacters string. If it is not the case, my apologies...

Anyway, I would use regular expressions for the purpose. Most of the characters you listed in specialCharacters should be escaped for a regular expression. So the code would look like:

```
string specialCharacters = @"\~|!|\@|\#|\$|%|\^|\&|\*|_|\+|\||\{|\}|:\""|\<|\>|\?|\[|\]|;|'|/|=|\\|№";

public bool ValidateCharacters(string pattern, AddressViewModel model)
{
    var reg = new Regex(pattern);

    return reg.IsMatch(model.Index) == false && reg.IsMatch(model.Area) == false;
}
```

I did some refactoring on the names and I would rather make this method a member function of AddressViewModel. Furthermore, there are very good articles about validation supported by the .Net framework, for example [this](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/).

Answer (score 4):

Well you can start by just having a return statement:

```
private bool ValidateCharacters(string specialCharacters, AddressViewModel x)
{
    return !x.Index.Any(specialCharacters.Contains) &&
           !x.Area.Any(specialCharacters.Contains);
}
```

Do you *need* to vary `specialCharacters` between calls? If not, you could remove it as a parameter and just have a private constant field. You might also want to extract a private method to compare a *single* string, so that you could just call:

```
private bool ValidateCharacters(string specialCharacters, AddressViewModel x)
{
    return ValidateCharacters(x.Index) &&
           ValidateCharacters(x.Area);
}
```

Or if you have a lot of strings, you could even (at slight performance overhead) create a method with a `params` parameter, and use:

```
private bool ValidateCharacters(string specialCharacters, AddressViewModel x)
{
    return ValidateCharacters(x.Index, x.Area, x.StreetName, x.Home, ...);
}
```

Comment: When it comes to the distributive property with bools, is there any  decent reason to choose `!(x || y)` over `!x && !y` or is it pretty much just personal preference?

Comment: @Jonesy: I prefer to avoid the bracketing if possible. I find it easier to read.

Comment: @Jonesy: No, it isn't true. If `x` is `true`, `y` is not evaluated and the complete statement inside the brackets evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @Sayse: No, they will exit at the same time. If `x` is `true`, both `!(x || y)`  and `!x && !y` will shortcircuit and avoid evaluating `y`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Ah of course, I'll stick to drinking my much needed caffiene

Comment: @JonSkeet - How about ArgumentNullException in Any? Some of propertie can be null

Comment: @user2469940: Doesn't that mean that your existing code fails too? I thought the point was to *refactor* the code, not fix brokenness.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Properties: Index, Area, Home, ... can be null

Comment: @user2469940: Well I don't have time to fix it now - but that's another reason to extract out a separate method, either for a single string or multiple strings as an array.